# How to unpack NTP UDP packet using pcap

Tags: sockets, udp, pcap

I can read UDP packet using

```
void my_callback(u_char *useless, const struct pcap_pkthdr* pkthdr, const u_char* packet)
```

I have hexa output of my packet:

```
08 00 27 E5 B5 3B 52 54 00 12 35 02 08 00 45 00 00 4C 7C E7 00 00 40 11 3C 28 5B BD 59 C6 0A 00 02 0F 00 7B 00 7B 00 38 B7 9D 24 02 03 E8 00 00 04 A8 00 00 07 51 83 BC 03 DC DC C5 CC 47 F1 F1 69 C3 DC C5 CF 37 D2 5F A7 F5 DC C5 CF 38 3C 2D C2 CF DC C5 CF 38 3C 32 0B 9A
```

I know, that it is `NTP` packet.

How can I extrath data? Cut ethernet frames, etc..

Thank you for your help.

I am using pcap c++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read pcap you get raw packet from the network device. Several options may be there:

- Packet is read from ethernet device
- Packet is read from vlan device
- Packet is read from some other device

What kind of device is used during pcap defines what protocol header is first in your packet. To know it you can look at link layer type field of global pcap header.

Once you defined first protocol header you need to open protocol specification and find:

- Size of header (in your case it looks like regular ethenet header - 14 bytes `08 00 27 E5 B5 3B 52 54 00 12 35 02 08 00`)
- How to find encapsulated packet type (in your case last `08 00` means IP)

Once you found IP header (`45 00 00 4C 7C E7 00 00 40 11 ...`) you can determine IP header length:

```
    0                   1                   2                   3
    0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1
   +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
   |Version|  IHL  |Type of Service|          Total Length         |
   +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
   |         Identification        |Flags|      Fragment Offset    |
   +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
   |  Time to Live |    Protocol   |         Header Checksum       |
   +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
   |                       Source Address                          |
   +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
   |                    Destination Address                        |
```

Here you need:

- IHL defines sizeof IP header. This is lower 4 bits of first byte of IP header. In your case it is 0x5. This means 5 words or 20 bytes.
- Protocol defines what data is encapsulated in IP header. In your case 0x11 (IPPROTO_UDP)

After that you can get UDP header (8 bytes) check ports if you need it and parse NTP header in according to NTP specification.

In your example total shift of the NTP header will be 14+20+8 bytes.